# I am unable to view sitefinity front end web pages without logged in?

Tags: upgrade, sitefinity

I recently upgraded my sitefinity solution from 8.0.5774 to 13.3.7600. After upgrading, when I loaded my solution it always takes me to the sitefiniy backend login page insted of showing home page. After getting logged in, that is as a authenticated user I am able browse/view the pages but as a public user or without logged in I am unable to browse/view pages. Without logged in, whenever I load page on browser It always takes me to the sitefinity log in page.

To resolve the issue, I have also followed the
[article](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/homepage-is-redirecting-to-the-login-page-after-upgrade) but it was not worked.

Comment: do you mean you can only view the Pages in the backend and all the other menus are hidden? Are you part of the Administrators role?

Comment: Backend is fine. If I load pages on browser as public user without logged in it takes me to sitefinity backend log in page it means publically I can't browse pages and  as an authenticated user I am able to browse/view pages. I have also updated my question.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the pages - do they allow Anonymous views?

Comment: Yes. In page permission, I have set "View this page and its child pages" to "Everyone".
https://www.screencast.com/t/fzXkX3Kis

Comment: Hard to say without closer look, I am afraid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I observed the following lines in the web.config file:

```
<location>
<system.web>
<authorization>
<deny users="?" />
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

The question mark (?) is a wildcard character that matches any user name. The code above denies access to all users. So when I comment out lines in the web config file then I am able to access my front end page without logging in.